# What is the math behind popular Bitcoin graphs? I want to graph Namecoin (or similar *coin) technologies?

Tags: namecoin, charts, technical-analysis

How can I create graphs similar to http://bitcoin.sipa.be, and blockchain.info for Namecoin?

For example [this thread discusses how to analyze difficulty over time](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2345.msg31405) and provides this  [equation and correlation covering 4 difficulty adjustments.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exponential%20fit%20%7B90720,4536%7D,%7B92736,6867%7D,%7B94752,8078%7D,%7B96768,12252%7D)

I'd like to understand the math required to create such graphs so I can port the trending to other *coin usages. (which invariably have different values)

Comment: Seems to me to be way too general and vague to be suitable for SE. Also, I don't think there's a shortcut - learn more math, especially in the areas of probability and statistics, and you'll have a better idea of what things can be analyzed and how to use different tools for it.

Comment: @MeniRosenfeld  Edited... what do you think?

Comment: Still feels a bit general, but maybe others will find a good way to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The math behind those graphs is pretty simple, the main problem is crawling through the data and creating readable images automatically.

Difficulty (red line) can always be read from the generated Blocks, no problem there.

1/3/7/14/whatever-window estimates I assume are calculated by counting how many Blocks were generated in a given time period and at what difficulty. In general I guess it should be:

Estimate = (Difficulty * MeasurementTime) / (10 minutes * BlockCount)